# Show hidden password, different browsers

Tags: html, browser, passwords

I am currently working on a web application at work. Previously, the browser we supported was only Internet Explorer, while now we are moving to Chrome and others. In IE9, the password field shows a little eye-like image to the right side of the input field, and when the user clicks it, the password as you typed it is shown. This is completely gone in Chrome, and I am unsure if there is some functionality I missed to port over to the new code. At first glance, it does not seem so, looking at the code - so my thoughts are that it might be something that is controlled or supported by the browser.
Does anyone have more insight into this? I would like to know if this behaviour is supported by Chrome, (or any browser you might be using).

I googled, but the searches that comes back all says something about right - clicking on the password field, and then to go to Inspect element. This is not what I want to do. I would ideally have the eye-like thingy back, and when clicked, the password will be displayed as it was typed, in the password input field itself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [a feature of IE](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/wiki/ie11-iewindows8_1/the-use-of-the-password-reveal-eye-button-in-ie10/19a9dee2-fb0c-4c26-a6bc-ac02cf98d80e). No other browser I know of implements it. If you want it, you'll have to replicate it using Javascript; though some browsers may or may not make this difficult since the input of a password field is explicitly obfuscated.